# Is there a way to add the last edited Date on a Google Data Studio report?

Tags: google-analytics, data-science, data-analysis, looker-studio

I'm working on a dashboard in Google Data Studio and my manager would like to have the last edited time of the Data Studio report displayed on a page in the report. I'm using  Google Sheets as the data source for all the charts used. (I do not want to display the date when the Sheet was last edited, but the date when the Data Studio Report was last edited.)

I've tried adding a scorecard and messing around with the fields and formulas to display the date, but I'm only able to show the current date and not the date when the report was last edited.

I'm guessing maybe there's a way to connect to Google Analytics to make this possible, I'm not really sure how. Although, if there's a way without using Google Analytics, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Data Studio expert, so there might be a way.
But from what I gather from https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9265174, *easy* access to version history requires report edit permissions:

> **Limits of version history**
>
> - In order to see version history, you must have edit permission to the report or data source .

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I understand that there is a way to view the version history, but is there a way to add the date of the last version to a page somehow? So that everyone can see the date on the page itself, instead of going to the version history.